# Show there exists a unitary matrix $C$ such that $C^{-1}AC=B$, where $B_{21} =B_{31} =0$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose $ A= \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 2 & 2 \\
2 & 0 & 3 \\
2 & 3 & 0 \end{array} \right) $

How to show there exists a unitary matrix $C$ such that $C^{-1}AC=B$, where $B_{21} =B_{31} =0$.

I appreciate some hints or solutions. Thank you.

Comment: Have you heard of permutations and conjugation of permutations? $$\sigma(1,2,3)\sigma^{-1}=\big(\sigma(1),\sigma(2),\sigma(3)\big)$$

Comment: @Fimpellizieri Yes! But I don't see how they are related, though.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri that won't work.  Conjugating by a permutation leaves the $0$s on the diagonal.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Hmm, is it a QR decomposition problem?

Comment: @Keenan I'd say that this problem is probably a lead in to Schur triangularization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The matrix is real symmetric, so has an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors. With $C$ the matrix whose columns describe that basis, $C^{-1}AC$ is a diagonal matrix; this is more than was asked for.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** It suffices to select a unitary matrix $C$ whose first column is an eigenvector of $A$.